# Pythonのロギング設定ファイルで記載されている`ext://sys.stdout`の`ext`の意味を調べるには、どのように検索すればよいでしょうか？

Tags: python, google-search

#### 背景

Pythonのログギング設定ファイルのサンプルコードに、`ext://sys.stdout`という文字列があります。
この`ext`の意味を調べるため、Googleで`"ext://sys.stdout"`を検索しましたが、検索結果は0件でした（2019/04/28実施）。

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
loggers:
  simpleExample:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging

#### 質問

`ext`の意味を調べるため、私はどのように検索すればよかったのでしょうか？

以下のページに`ext`の意味は載っていました。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/library/logging.config.html#access-to-external-objects

しかし、このページにはたまたま辿り着いただけでして、`ext`の意味を調べようと思って見つけたページではありません。

今後同じようなことが起きても調べられるよう、対応方法を知っておきたいです。

Comment: Google の検索語を入力するテキストボックスで `python ext://` と入力していくと、検索候補として `python ext sys.stdout` が表示されました。それで検索すると当該の説明ページがヒットします。

Comment: 後から気がついたのですが、コロン(`:`)の直前にバックスラッシュ( \ )を置くと(`python ext\://sys.stdout`)、`ext://sys.stdout` として認識してくれる様です。

Comment: (1) その例の直後にわざわざ「辞書を使ったロギングについて詳細は、 環境設定のための関数を参照してください。」とリンクまであるのだからそれを辿る (2) 仕様に疑問があればまずはリファレンスマニュアルを参照する、のいずれかの行動パターンなら辿り着けたと思います

Comment: コロンをエスケープすればよかったんですね！
コロンは`site:youtube.com`のようにサイト検索で使われるので、エスケープが必要なんですかね。
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@metropolis さんのコメントが役に立ちました。

> 後から気がついたのですが、コロン(`:`)の直前にバックスラッシュ( `\` )を置くと(`python ext\://sys.stdout`)、`ext://sys.stdout` として認識してくれる様です

コロンは`site:youtube.com`のようにサイト検索で使われるので、エスケープが必要なんですかね。
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

この件に関しては、(ソースを見るくらいしか) 無さそうで、Python ドキュメントの不備と言っていいと思います。

[ソースを見ると](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/logging/config.py)、スキームとして `ext` と `cfg` が定義されています。これは Python 独自のものです (URI のスキームとして登録されているわけではない)。

これは不具合でありレアケースであり、これを持って一般的な調査方法を、と考える必要はないと思います (強いていうなら [Python のバグトラッカー](https://bugs.python.org/) に報告する、とか)。